# Sitecore 9 CMS - Add an Image to a Link in the Footer

Tags: links

A client is using Sitecore 9 - we are not Sitecore developers.

We've been asked a simple thing: add social media links to the Footer of their Sitecore site.

Its proving more difficult than expected.

I've added the links on other pages by editing the HTML directly via the WYSWIG editor.

But the Footer appears more restricted, only accepting the addition of templates like 'Link'.

The 'Link' template has an option to add an external URL but doesn't have an option to add an image.

The CMS looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to add a link, with an image, via the CMS (without the need to write Sitecore code), so the page chnages from this:

[image: no lines]

to this:

[image: links inserted]

**UPDATE 21.05.21**

I've now figured out how to create my own template which, seemingly, does what I want: A Link field + an image field + an extra text field

[image]

Here is the instance of the User Defined Template, which is 'inherited' from the 'General Link' template:

[image]

However, the CMS refuses to render the sections of the User Defined Template i.e. the Image and Text fields. My guess is: the containing folder is a "Link Menu" instance and Sitecore appears to only render "Link Menu Items". For example, I added a standard "Button" instance under that folder...and that doesn't render either.

Screenshot of the rendered page:

[image]

And the markup clearly shows that the new Template renders but the extra fields do not:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why the extra fields in my template don't render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question, I can see that there is no existing implementation for your requirements. So there is no anyway for you, you need to write Sitecore code. Here the Link field is a `General Link` field and it does not accept any image in it, you need a separate image field for the social media Icons, although there are multiple ways to handle it using CSS as well. but having an image field is always a good option.

**Update**-
So far what you did is almost correct, but it will require updating the code as well in the `.cs` file or/and `.cshtml` view file to render the image in between anchor tag.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've added some extra info as an update...would you mind having a look?

Comment: @JTech - you need to update your code as well after adding new field or creating new template